Multiple declared UseMessageRetry method reset re-try counter in MassTransit
I use masstransit 8 + amazon sqs/sns, the app is running in Windows Docker container.
I have a single consumer, where following exceptions can occur: EndpointNotFoundException, TimeoutException, SocketException.
To handle these exceptions I use 3 separate re-try policies that have different time interval.
builder.Services
       .Configure<AmazonSqsTransportOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MassTransit:Transports:AmazonSqs"))
       .AddMassTransit(bus =>
       {
           bus.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

           bus.AddConsumer<MySingleConsumer>();

           bus.UsingAmazonSqs((context, sqs) =>
           {
               var entityNameFormatter = new MessageNameFormatterEntityNameFormatter(new AmazonSqsMessageNameFormatter());

               var options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AmazonSqsTransportOptions>>().Value;
               sqs.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(new PrefixEntityNameFormatter(entityNameFormatter, options.Scope));

               sqs.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter(options.Scope));

               sqs.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
               
               sqs.UseMessageRetry(r =>
               {
                   r.Handle(typeof(EndpointNotFoundException));
                   
                   r.Interval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
               });

               sqs.UseMessageRetry(r =>
               {
                   r.Handle(typeof(TimeoutException));

                   r.Interval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
               });

               sqs.UseMessageRetry(r =>
               {
                   r.Handle(typeof(SocketException));

                   r.Interval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
               });
           });
       });

Now, if exception of one type will occur sequentially 3 times then re-try policy will handle it correctly - i.e. the exception will finally be thrown after 3 re-try attempts in row.
The problem is if exceptions occur in random order - for instance - first EndpointNotFoundException, then TimeoutException, then SocketException, and again EndpointNotFoundException.
In this case the counter of exception attempt is reset to 0 and to re-throw the EndpointNotFoundException you need to wait again for it to occur 3 in row.
Here are the examples:

EndpointNotFoundException occurs 3 times in row => the next EndpointNotFoundException will be re-thrown - CORRECT.

EndpointNotFoundException occurs 3 times in row, then TimeoutException occurs 1 time - it reset the counter of EndpointNotFoundException exception to 0 and you have to wait again EndpointNotFoundException to occur 3 times in row for it be re-thrown - INCORRECT.

SocketException occurs 3 time, TimeoutException occurs 3 times, again SocketException occurs 3 time - only after this SocketException is re-thrown - INCORRECT.

SocketException occurs 1 time, TimeoutException occurs 2 times, EndpointNotFoundException occurs 2 times, then if SocketException occurs 3 times only then it will be finally re-thrown - INCORRECT.


In other words in 'remembers' only the attempts of last exception in row. If occurs other exception - it reset the attempt counter. It could potentially lead to endless loop of exceptions re-tries, say EndpointNotFoundException 1 time, TimeoutException 1 time, SocketException 1 time, then again EndpointNotFoundException 1 time, again TimeoutException 1 time - and so one as every next exception which is different from previous one - always reset the attempts counter to 0.
I noted the counter works incorrect when multiple sqs.UseMessageRetry() methods are using for every type of exception.
If all exceptions are declared within only one in sqs.UseMessageRetry() policy - then the counter works correctly for any random order of exceptions.
Probably, I've misunderstand something in how re-try policy works, could you please advice ? It's easy to re-produce, should I put it as bug in GitHub ?
Thanks,
Evgeny.

That's how it works, the behavior is as expected. If you want to retry multiple exception types with the same limit, put them into the same block.

Hi Chris. The problem is that limit and re-try interval are differenct for every specific exception type. But it makes sense, thank you. I'll put all exceptions to the same block and adjust average time interval.
